# Most efficient way of flooring todays date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

This seems like overkill but is the only way I have been able to floor todays datetime to 00:00:00.000 at database level:

```
select CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS float)) AS DATETIME)
```

I have tried using:

```
select FLOOR(getdate())
```

But get the following message:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to float is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run `this query.`

Can anyone recommend another way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you could make use of the `date` data type.

```
declare @Today date

set @Today = getdate()

select @Today
```

Or without the variable.

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

If you need to have the value as a datetime just cast it back to a datetime.

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)
```

Comment: The results needs to be datetime as I have a function elsewhere that will be reading the value and checking both the date and time. Will this still work if it is a date data type?

Comment: It will *probably* be implicitly converted but to make sure you can just convert it back to a `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing this i have seen the floor one before.  Here are a few more.

```
select cast(cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) as datetime)

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0) 

SELECT CAST(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.50000004 AS int) AS datetime)
```

I normaly do the Cast to date version.